# How to make a raspberry pi 2 laravel 5.1 server

Tags: raspberry-pi, laravel-routing, raspberry-pi2, laravel-5.1

I want to build a laravel 5.1 server on a raspberry pi 2. But i can't find any information about how to make it. Any suggestions to would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'm in the process of doing this.  I discovered a few things that are worth noting:

1)  Composer is not in Debian and by extension not in Raspbian.  You will need to download and install it manually.

I followed this guide:  http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2014/08/how-to-install-composer-on-debian/  However, it tells you to install to /usr/bin, which is bad.  Install to /user/local/bin/ instead (it's in your path by default anyway.

2)  Debian Wheezy, the Raspbian distribution shipped with the Pi does not support PHP >= 5.5.9, so trying to run artisan fails.  To do this, you need to upgrade to Jessie.

To do this, I opened my /etc/apt/sources.list and changed all occurrences of Wheezy to Jessie.  Then:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
```

Or Google any guide for how to upgrade wheezy to Jessie for the Raspbian

I still haven't successfully run a Laravel dev server yet, but this got me a whole lot of the way there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've done (on RASPBIAN JESSIE):

Installed apache/php5.6/mysql(from: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-lamp-on-debian-jessie/) -- *install mysql-server mysql-client *

Got Composer

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php5
```

*follow regular steps like moving composer to bin... add to $PATH ...*

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist projectName
```

And finally changed ownership of /var/www/ to Apache's user (www-data) and permissions of app folder

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 775 projectName
```

Answer (score 1):

Install raspbian distribution, and then just follow any webserver guide for debian (just make sure that you install and enable all required PHP extensions listed in installation part of laravel doc)
If there is no composer package for pi you'd have to prepare project on your main PC and then upload it to pi

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Lumen running on a Raspberry Pi B+ so I'm guessing Laravel would be possible too.

As aphenine mentioned, you need to update the sources.list to jessie, running the update and upgrade commands to bring everything up to speed.

Then I used this command:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client apache2 php5 php5-cli libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php-pear php5-imagick php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-sqlite php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-json php5-dev libpcre3-dev
```

to install a LAMP stack.

Credit to this website: http://snippets.khromov.se/debian-lamp-stack-in-one-command/

You can't use composer straight away here so all your development needs to be on another computer and move it across to the Raspberry Pi (e.g. (S)FTP).